# Start a circuit or device when you insert key in car ignition

Tags: electrical, ignition, key

I want to start a circuit in my car when I insert my key in car ignition and let it turn off when the key gets removed. I have Honda Civic 2007.
Can someone just help me out as to from where do I take 12v connection which switches ON when a key gets inserted and switches Off when key gets removed. NOTE that I don't want to wait for a key to turn On the main ignition i.e ACC.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I'm sorry I'm not any expert in electronics or electrical system. I'm a professional software developer and this is my hobby project. Actually my car security system doesn't allow the ignition system to On until I press a provided button switch hidden in console below the steering wheel. So I got an idea to replace that switch with an RFID card system. My RFID card system was a success and I tested that and everything works fine. But my system is connected all the time since I connected it with the main 12v line. Which I don't want. I only want it to run when I insert key so I could touch card which will ultimately switches On the main ignition system. And then only turn my system Off when I remove the key from the ignition system.

Comment: Is there anything right now that turns on when you just insert your key?

Comment: yes, my odometer area lits up a little. And when I remove my key it gets dimmed down and turn off ultimately.

Comment: There probably is a switch. Does your car warn you if you leave the key in the ignition? But knowing how to connect up to that switch is specialized information. Maybe nobody on this forum will know exactly how to do it without experimenting with it. Maybe the information would be in a wiring diagram for your car.

Comment: Exactly, car beeps if I leave the key and opens door.

Comment: Maybe I need help to find out exact fuse number in the fuse box.

Comment: A device that turns on by inserting a key without turning the key will turn on if you insert a stiff wire like a straightened paper clip.

Comment: If a light illuminates, why not use an input on a micro controller to detect the voltage on the light?

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Where do I tap my wire to get that +ve voltage so my circuit gets turned On. But I just don't know where. I searched the fuse panel but there are a lot of fuses with barely information.

Comment: Here's a bunch of a good info for multimeters.  You'll need to use one to validate your getting the right circuit and it actually get's power when you turn your key on before you do all of the wiring.     http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags/multimeter/info

Comment: Put a sensor in your seat that completes a circuit when someone sits in it. (Sounds silly, but your car already has these - they're used for airbag control.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pretty safe fuse protected accessory circuit in your car is the one that powers your audio system. According to [this information](http://www.modifiedlife.com/2007-honda-civic-car-stereo-radio-wiring-diagram/), you're looking for the following wires:

> Car Radio Switched 12v+ Wire: Violet
>   Car Radio Ground Wire: Black

By tapping into these wires, you can safely add a low power accessory circuit.

Alternatively, if you need more power than say, 1A, I usually use a piggyback fuse adapter like this:
[image: Piggyback fuse adapter]

There are a few styles of this kind of adapter available to match the fuse type in your vehicle. These adapter let you remove an existing fuse, insert the adapter and insert the original fuse and a new fuse for the new circuit that can be powered from the new flying lead. Find a fuse that's only live when the ignition is in ACC mode (audio system radio fuse perhaps?).

If you really want to enable your new accessory circuit only when the key is inserted but not even turned to ACC yet, you will need to sense the "key inserted" signal. This signal is pulled up by the MICU and grounded by the key inserted switch. Here's the schematic:
[image: immobilizer 1 of 2]
[image: immobilizer 2 of 2]

You could add a small +12VDC relay that's connected to "always hot" and protected by a fuse and activated by tapping into the Pink "key detect" wire which goes to ground when a key is inserted. This relay could then provide the power to your new accessory circuit. I would avoid adding a new 1A circuit directly grounded by the "key inserted" switch since this tiny microswitch is not designed to carry significant power but rather only as a small signal switch to ground to be detected by the MICU.

Comment: I like your idea but I don't want to wait for the ACC mode ON. When you insert key in ignition a little light lits up in odometer. Which indicates that something knows that a key has been just inserted and when I remove the key that light goes Off. So basically I need to find that switch or fuse in the fuse box and then I can use this adapter.

Comment: And my circuit only needs maybe 500-900 milliamps and won't be needing more than 1A.

Comment: Exactly what light lights up in the "odometer"? do you mean the instrument panel? Is it the security immobilizer light with a key symbol?

Comment: modified answer to include information on "key detected" switch. now that it's been moved to this new forum, I need upvotes here to get enough reputation to comment everywhere.

Comment: poking around at just the fuses (as suggested by other answer) will not achieve what you need. even if you find the fuse for the circuit that lights up the "odometer" (instrument panel?) light, it will be live all the time and the indicator light controlled by the MICU instead.

Comment: yes the instrument panel. I really want to keep the circuit On while the key has been inserted and even after the car gets started. So the only time my circuit will go Off would be when I engine Off my car and get that key Off from the switch.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not any expert in electronics or electrical system. I'm a professional software developer and this is my hobby project. Actually my car security system doesn't allow the ignition system to On until I press a provided button switch hidden in console below the steering wheel. So I got an idea to replace that switch with an RFID card system. My RFID card system was a success and I tested that and everything works fine. But my system is connected all the time since I connected it with the main 12v line. Which I don't want. I only want it to run when I insert key so I could touch card

Comment: Which will ultimately switches On the main ignition system. And then only turn my system Off when I remove the key from the ignition system.

Comment: I've described how to accomplish this in my modified answer above

Comment: hmm Ok. I will try doing this. If it worked I'll update here. Thanks a lot Bartman.

Answer (score 2):

To find the correct circuit you could probe the fuses. Check the voltage or insert an ampere meter instead of the fuse while inserting the key. Beware that you might blow the fuse of the ampere meter... My bets are on No 10 or 9:

[image]

Comment: That looks something really helpful. I will try probing them and then get back. I'm hopeful now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've played in the 12v world but there will be a line (probably provides ground but possibly is powered) that is used to signal the "key reminder".  This is the ding that goes off when you forget key in the ignition and open the door.  For this to work there is a circuit closure at the ignition switch/assembly just by putting the key in.  Find this circuit and you'll have your signalling line.

If that line is just a ground (or a lower voltage i.e. just for signaling), then use that line to trigger a small relay and have the relay switch through the 12v you need.